# C# Decimal type rounding off inappropriately

Tags: c#, sql-server, floating-point, rounding-error

I've got an in house banking solution for a summer camp that I'm a part of. The issue is coming up that some accounts are exactly a penny off at the end of the season.

I'm using SQL Server Express, with two tables. One table with all accounts, which holds their current balance. The other table is a running transaction log. The idea is that if I were to sum up all the transactions in the log, it should equal the current account balance for any given account.

But it doesn't. For example, I sum the database and see that a given account should have `$15.10`, but the account table shows that they have a balance of `$15.09`

Here is the relevant code:

```
//Amount is negative, they bought something
if (amount <= 0)
{
    //Check if they have enough money to buy, or they are a paid account type (faculty, staff)

    if (account.Balance >= Math.Abs(amount) || account.AccountType > AccountType.Camper)
        account.Balance -= Math.Abs(amount);
    else
        return Error.LowBalance;
}
else
{
    account.Balance += Math.Abs(amount);
}

var t = new Transaction
{
    AccountId = account.Id,
    Amount = amount,
    SubmittedBy = username,
    TransactionRefId = refId,
    ComputerHostname = hostname,
    Location = location,
    Notes = notes
};

_db.Transactions.Add(t);
_db.SaveChanges();
```

I'm using Entity Framework, code-first. The datatype for `Account.Balance`, `amount`, and `Transaction.Amount` are all `System.Decimal`

I don't understand why there is a rounding error, I'm using all the proper datatypes for this situation. The usual way that I see this is when they have two different transactions for `$0.75`. For some reason the code is saying `0.05 + 0.05 = 0.09`

In my database, the `Accounts.Balance` column datatype is `decimal(18,2)`

I understand that floating point numbers can do this sometime, but I'm looking for a fix. I thought I was covered by using the `System.Decimal` datatype.

Comment: What do you mean by "the code is saying 0.05 + 0.05 = 0.09"? It's unclear what you're seeing where.

Comment: Can you use the debugger to find the exact line of code that is resulting in a rounding error?

Comment: Have you tried changing the type to Money? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179882.aspx

Comment: @JonSkeet As in thats what seems to be happening. If I apply a transaction for $0.75, then another for $0.75 the system shows the balance equalling $1.49

Comment: But where are you seeing that? If the arithmetic is being performed locally, you should be able to log each value being added, and the result at each point - and then reproduce it without the database being involved. It's all still unclear...

Comment: I see it after the fact. `account` is an entity framework tracked object. When I save the changes to the database, the `Account.Balance` property is pushed to the database table. For some reason there is a rounding error happening there. If I look at that row in the SQL table after the fact, I see a balance that is off by a penny. Its not the summing of transactions that is off. The problem lies in the `account.Balance -= Math.Abs(amount);`, or as Alexandre pointed out in an answer, it could be in the database.

Comment: Use SQL profiler to see what SQL is being executed. Then you know whether to look in C# for the bug or if it's on the database side.

Comment: @AdamSchiavone If that is correct (to be honest, I suspect it's not), then you should be able to easily come up with a minimal reproducer. Write a program that sets the property to `1.50m` and saves it to the database. If it stores something other than `1.50`, then edit your question to show the program that has that behaviour. If it stores `1.50`, then the problem is not what you say it is.

Comment: There's one of two ways you could handle it.  Personally, if you're likely not going to be dealing with huge sums of money or fractional cents, I'd just store the cost as an integer (representing the number of cents) and change how it's being displayed at runtime.  The other option as has been pointed out is to use the money type.  Both of these are acceptable, depending on how your system is set up.

Answer (score 0):

You are only storing 2 decimal digits and throwing off everything after it,  losing the precision in the process. Store more decimal digits.

Another example of losing precision: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/145d2b1c-793a-4d3e-8cbf-ac9bcc6dd273/rounding-c-decimal-values-to-sql-decimal-or-numeric-fields?forum=adodotnetentityframework

Comment: So I need to change the `decimal(18, 2)` to something like `decimal(18, 4)`?

Comment: Or more, depending on the reliability you want, Decimal in C# is just a "Double with more bits" but cannot be trusted either.

Comment: I don't believe this answer applies. That article is about truncation when you're saving a number with say 10 decimals into a db field with only 2. It truncates, not rounds. In his case, the database has the room to store the value correctly.

Comment: @AlexandreBorela `decimal` is not just a higher precision `double`.  The `decimal` type represents values as an integer multiplied by a power of 10 (technically always a negative power of 10), not a power of 2.  This means that `decimal` can represent 1/5 precisely (2 * 10^-1) where `double` cannot.

Comment: @Kyle Yeah, i might have exaggerated there xD, thanks man, still i think the problem is that he's losing precision, some transactions having a value 1/3 would do this in the long run.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx this is directly related to the proposed solution.